# Effects of linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, plane-geometry

Suppose we have a rotation matrix $P$ and a diagonal matrix $D$. 
How do you explain the effect of $D$ as a linear transformation on the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ geometrically?
What about the effect of $P^{-1}DP$?

My approach:
Well whenever we apply a diagonal matrix 
\begin{bmatrix} 
    a & 0 \\
    0 & b 
\end{bmatrix}
on a vector, we just rescale the vector thus we just stretch the $\mathbb{R}^2$ plane.

Then for $P^{-1}DP$ we first rotate the vector, stretch and then bring it all back. So in this case what is the answer?

Comment: It is a stretch along axes, but not the vertical/horizontal axes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The effect of $D$ is a rescaling with dilation/contraction of the $2$ axes.

The effect of $P^{-1}DP$ is a rescaling with dilation/contraction in the direction $-\theta$ and $-\theta + 90°$.

Comment: Why in that direction?

Comment: @mandella Since with $P$ we rotate by $\theta$ than we apply $D $the we rotate of $-\theta$ by $P^{-1}$

Comment: Makes sense. What about an explanation with eigenvectors/orthobasis ? Do you have any idea about that

Comment: By eigenvalues you shoul precisely find out for $P^{-1}DP$ the eigenvectros in the direction $-\theta$ and $-\theta+90°$ associated with the eigenvalues $a$ and $b$.

Comment: but what does it mean to rescale and dilate/contract in two directions ?

Comment: @mandella it means that we find two eigenvalues suche that $Av=av$ and $Aw=bw$ with $v$ in direction $-\theta$ and $w$ in direction $-\theta +90°$.

Comment: but why not $\theta$ and $\theta + 90^ \circ$

Comment: I do not understand why $\theta$ and $-\theta +90^ \circ$!

Comment: Note that by $P^{-1}DP$ we are applying forst $P$ then $D$ and finally $P^{-1}$. Assuming that $P$ rotates of $\theta$ when we apply D we have the dilation/contraction applied in the (new) axis direction. Then we apply $P^{-1}$ which rotates the system of $-\theta$, thus the new principal direction for dilation/contraction are rotated of -$\theta$ and $-\theta+90°$. If you don't get it tru to do some sketches or try with a numerical example.

Comment: But doesn't $\theta$ and then $-\theta$ just change it back to normal?

Comment: @mandella I've given all kind of explanation, let try by yourself with some numerical example.

Comment: @mandella finally did you get it?

Comment: Yes! :) it's okay thank you

Comment: @mandella Well done! I'm very happy for that! Bye